# Stickers Packs outside GBoard

Tags: android, firebase, google-app-indexing, gboard

Now that Android has the option to release stickers packs to the Play Store, I want to know if there is any way to detect (and use) the packs installed in the device.

Right know, from GBoard, you can see, use and install new stickers packs (discoverable trough Firebase Indexing system) but I want to be able to access those packs from my app without using the keyboard
(my app allows users to add stickers/text to pictures, but I have a different UI for both cases, and it doesn't make sense to choose the text option to add stickers while I already have a stickers only UI)

Comment: See also this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51263655/gboard-keyboard-gif-sticker-integration/55316547#55316547

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to do that right now, sorry!